# C++ Access violation writing location when adding strings to a dynamic array

Tags: c++, string, templates, dynamic-arrays

I'm implementing a dynamic array. My default array capacity is 10. When I'm trying to add more than 10 randomized strings I'm getting an error "Access violation writing location. this-> **_Myproxy ** was 0xFDFDFDFD." and I'm thrown to the 239th line of xutility file.

However when I set my array to contain ints or chars it works just fine. Same when I'm adding less than 10 strings so I have no idea where the problem is. Maybe I'm releasing memory in a twisted way?

This is my main function as well as Arr class' constructor, destructor and void add function.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

template < typename T >
class Arr
{
    T * data;
    int capacity, len;
public:
    Arr()
    {
        capacity = 10;
        len = 0;
        data = new T[ capacity ];
    }
    ~Arr()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }
    void add( T value )
    {
        if( capacity <= len ) //powiekszenie jesli nie ma miejsca
        {
            capacity = 2 * capacity;
            T * temp = new T[ capacity ];
            for( int i = 0; i <= len; i++ )
            {
                //temp[i] = data[i];
                temp[ i ] = move( data[ i ] );
            }
            delete[] data;
            data = temp;
        }
        data[ len++ ] = value;
    }
    const T retVal( const int index )
    {
        if( index >= len )
        {
            cout << "Nie ma elementu o takim indeksie, zwracam wartosc el.     
        [0]: ";
        return this->data[ 0 ];
    }
    else
         return this->data[ index ];

    }
    void change( int index, T new_data )
    {
        if( index > len )
        {
            cout << "Nie ma takiego elementu" << endl;
            return;
        }
        data[ index ] = new_data;
    }
    void clean()
    {
        if( len == 0 )
        {
            cout << "Tablica pusta!" << endl;
            return;
        }
        len = len - 1;
        for( int i = len; i >= 1; --i )
        {
            data[ i ].~T();
            len--;
        }
    }
    void getData()
    {
        cout << endl << "Akt. pojemnosc tablicy: " << capacity << endl;
        cout << "Liczba el. w tablicy: " << len << endl;
    }
    void delLast()
    {
        data[ len-- ].~T();
    }
    void printArr()
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        {
            cout << data[ i ] << " ";
        }
        //cout << "Koniec" << endl;
    }
};
string randomString( int length )
{
    string rs;
    static const char chars[] = 
  "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int size = sizeof( chars );
    for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        rs = rs + chars[ rand() %( size - 1 ) ];
    }
    return rs;
}
int main()
{
Arr < string > * tab = new Arr < string >();
const int order = 7;
const int n = pow( 10, order );
clock_t start = clock();
double max_time_per_element = 0.0;
srand( time( 0 ) );
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    string el = randomString( 3 );
    clock_t start2 = clock();
    tab->add( el );
    clock_t stop2 = clock();
    double time_per_element =( stop2 - start2 ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // obliczenie czasu pojedynczej operacji dodawania
    if( time_per_element > max_time_per_element )
    {
        time_per_element = max_time_per_element;
        cout << max_time_per_element << endl;
    }
}
clock_t stop = clock();
double general_time =( stop - start ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
tab->getData();
cout << "Czas calej operacji to: " << general_time << endl;
tab->printArr();
tab->clean(); // czyszczenie tablicy wraz z uwalnianiem pamieci danych
delete tab;
return 0;
}
```

[EDIT] As some of you suggestes I pasted the entire code instead of just some parts like at the beginning. Please forgive me that, I'm new here!

Comment: First line of Add function will overflow. Try (len-1). If capacity == 10 and len == 10, it will still try add an item. Only next iteration will grow, after the critical error

Comment: No, that `if` statement appears to be correct. The buffer overrun and undefined behavior is somewhere else. The buffer overrun seems to be obvious, however, there are obvious typos and truncation in the shown code that indicate that the shown code has been edited. It possible that the editing also hid additional issues, so until the shown code is fixes so that it meets all requirements of a [mre], it would be a bit premature (at least speaking for myself) to give the answer.

Comment: "I just added the parts where I think the mistakes are". That in itself is wrong. Instead, you should add everything that's necessary for the code to meet all requirements for [mre], that anyone can simply cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce your error. Right now, if what you showed is cut/pasted, it can't even compile. For more information, see [ask] in the [help].

Comment: Perhaps the loop which goes from 0->len which should be 0->(len-1)

Comment: That's probably the bug. However, in the past, in similar situations, once the obvious bug is pointed out, a little bit later you get a reply that says "gee, I made that change, but the code is still broken". That was because there was something else in the code that wasn't even shown, that was also broken, and I wasted my time typing up an answer. So, for that reason, my personal policy is to only post a minimal comment if the question does not have a [mre]. I must be able to cut/paste, reproduce the bug, apply my fix and recompile, and prove now that it's correct. Then I post an answer.